# Viewing child streams created with using std::thread

Tags: c++

I recently started learning multithreaded programming in C++. I'm creating multiple threads using std::thread inside a function main(). How can I view the child threads that a process creates main() in the operating system Linux Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS? I'm trying run utilities htop, ps -T -p, top -H -p, but i see only parent process without childs. Maybe, I'm not understand several details  ... Please, helped me!

The launch htop, ps -T -p htop, ps -T -p, top -H -p did not produce results.

```
#include <QCoreApplication> 
#include <thread> 
#include <QDebug> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <functional>  
using namespace std;  
void func() {     
     qDebug() << "_func_"; 
}  
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {     
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);      
thread t(&func);    
thread t1(&func);     
thread t2(&func);      
t.join();     
t1.join();     
t2.join();      
cout << "_threads_" << endl;      
return a.exec(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you show a [mre] of the code?

Comment: `#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <thread>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void func() {
    qDebug() << "_func_";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    thread t(&func);
    thread t1(&func);
    thread t2(&func);

    t.join();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    cout << "_threads_" << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
`

Comment: Each one of your execution threads finishes and disappears long before your fingers manage to finish typing the `ps` command. And if it was already running, you have a far better chance of winning the lottery than having `ps` or `top` refresh at the precise infinitessimal quantum that the execution thread actually exists.

Comment: ***[Edit]*** your question to add information, like code. Also, it's not really clear (to me at least) what the problem really is... What *streams* do you want to view? Is it just a problem of seeing the threads in `htop`? Perhaps your threads have exited too quickly so you don't see them?

Comment: Sam Varshavchik, Thank you. Please, tell me, suspend execution working process with this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000)) belivable?